# OpenCV Mat for Integer types only

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using an algorithm that requires a Mat image saved as unsigned integers only and not as unsigned char (uchar) provided by Mat(rows,cols,CV_8U). So far I tried using CV_8U and the algorithm fails when reading the uchar values. Is there a way I can save a Mat image as 8 bit of integers only?
Thanks.

Comment: did you mean CV_8UC4 instead of 'unsigned integer' ?

Comment: what do you mean by "saving" the image? Is it just about sending to harddrive (or sth)? or do you want to "work" with unsigned int type within your program?

Answer (score 11):

There is no Mat type for `unsigned int`. You can use `CV_32SC1` for an `int` type.

The list of types is available there : http://ninghang.blogspot.fr/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

---

In case the blog isn't available:

**Unsigned 8bits uchar 0~255**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_8U
Mat: CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2, CV_8UC3, CV_8UC4

**Signed 8bits char -128~127**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_8S
Mat: CV_8SC1，CV_8SC2，CV_8SC3，CV_8SC4

**Unsigned 16bits ushort 0~65535**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_16U
Mat: CV_16UC1，CV_16UC2，CV_16UC3，CV_16UC4

**Signed 16bits short -32768~32767**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_16S
Mat: CV_16SC1，CV_16SC2，CV_16SC3，CV_16SC4

**Signed 32bits int -2147483648~2147483647**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_32S
Mat: CV_32SC1，CV_32SC2，CV_32SC3，CV_32SC4

**Float 32bits float -1.18*10-38~3.40*10-38**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_32F
Mat: CV_32FC1，CV_32FC2，CV_32FC3，CV_32FC4

**Double 64bits double**
Mat: CV_64FC1，CV_64FC2，CV_64FC3，CV_64FC4

**Unsigned 1bit bool**
IplImage: IPL_DEPTH_1U